# How to make a pretty URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am creating my whole application with .html extension, to play with the database I am using jQuery Ajax. I have created the project structure like WordPress, for each file I am having a folder and inside that folder I am having an index.html file.

[image: File Structure]

In the above picture, I have created user/equipment/index.html, in this file all the equipment are being shown, now I want that if user clicks on an equipment then the URL should be like 'domain.com/user/equipment/equipment-title' and the file should be called user/equipment/details/index.html

I believe that this can be done with a .htaccess file.

Any solution for the problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to store the references in that index file the way you want them to be, request rewriting (wo which you refer as ".htaccess") cannot do that for you. Why you *can* do with request rewriting, so inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") is to the internally rewrite the incoming requests. For that you need a mapping from request URLs to your detail pages. If the mapping the simply the name as to be found in the "equipment" folder (this is unclear from your question), then you indeed can simply implement a rewriting rule.

This would be such an example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?user/equipment/(.*)/?$ /equipment/$1 [END]
```

This will deliver the content of the file `/equipment/equipment-title` when the URL `https://example.com/user/equipment/equipment-title` gets requested and that file exists.

For this to work the rewriting module has to be enabled inside your http server and, if you want to use a distributed configuration file for this, the interpretation of such files also needs to be enabled for that location inside your http server. Usually the better alternative is to place such rules in the real http server's host configuration, though.

Comment: I have already enabled rewrite module, the way I wanted to rewrite it was quite strange. cause I had the same URL path for both all equipment and specific equipment however I was passing an extra param while fetching a specific equipment but it didn't work for me.
RewriteRule ^user/equipment/(.*)$ ./user/equipments/details/index.html
this worked for me. :)